# What did Avraham Avinu's tent look like?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers

What did Avraham Avinu's tent look like? Is there an actual source for the idea that his tent had four doors - one on each side?

Comment: Why would you think to ask for an "actual source" for that? What makes you suggest that it has four doors?

Comment: What is an "actual source" and how does it differ from a non-actual source?

Comment: @DoubleAA. By actual source I mean some sort of Midrash or divrei chazal. I meant to exclude the only source I know of which is my kid's nursery morah.

Comment: @magicker72. My daughter's nursery teacher made me think to ask for an actual source.